# AddModule mod_php5.c not in httpd.conf

Tags: php, macos, apache

PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php says to uncomment this line: # AddModule mod_php5.c in /etc/httpd/httpd.conf, but the line is missing (same issue here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91933/unable-to-enable-php-in-osx-10-8-mountain-lion but for Yosemite)

Tried to see if updating using instructions from here: http://ziad.eljammal.com/install-php-5-5-on-mac-os-x/ (replace with 5.6) would help resolve, but it did not also install modules

How do you install modules? There are some solutions with Homebrew and other package installers, but will it update the httpd.conf file or create a new instance of it in another location? Do I need to get rid of the original php install then?  How do you make sure you don't keep unnecessary packages/versions?  What's the difference between a module and an extension?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, and I followed this guidehttp://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-yosemite/

The author doesn´t mention anything about the second line, and now I have everything working, so maybe it is not necessary anymore.